# no last call on a mock available happening only when calling testng via ant

Tags: java, ant, testng, powermock, easymock

My test stack is:

- **TestNG** - Bolding this because I see @runWith recommended as the solution when that's JUnit only
- EasyMock
- PowerMock's MockStatic

I've got a test class that I've annotated with @PrepareForTest(StaticClass.class)

And then in my test I'm doing a very simple

`PowerMock.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
StaticClass.method(parameter);
expectLastCall().anyTimes();`

I'm getting the standard "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available" issue, but ONLY when running TestNG from ant, not when running from Eclipse. I believe my classpath includes all the necessary .jar files as PowerMock.mockStatic() is being called fine and all jars were added to the same classpath.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post complete, run-able sample.

Comment: Hint: some feedback would be welcome. Now I have no idea if you find my answer insufficient, if you are looking for more/other information ...

Comment: Your answer is indeed insufficient as all you said was that it should be impossible when I'm seeing the error in front of me. I work on an enterprise application and thus cannot provide code. As far as the issue, I've been able to track it down to some incompatible versions and not overwriting the object factory. And yes, while the best solution would be to have no static calls, that's not always possible and I found your statement of "learn how to create testable code" fairly condescending. I'll answer the question with information regarding the incompatible versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ended up being with some incompatible versions of powermock and testng as well as not overwriting the object factory as mentioned [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/testng_usage)